# C++ Fibonacci Errors

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I'm having some trouble with this non recursive Fibonacci function. I am using this array of numbers and passing it to `FiboNR`, however I am getting large negative values and Access Violation errors.

```
int n[15] = { 1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70 };

int FiboNR(int n) // array of size n
{
     int const max = 100;
     int F[max];
     F[0] = 0; F[1] = 1;
     for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
         F[n] = F[n - 1] + F[n - 2];
     }
  return (F[n]);
}
```

The function was one provided by the instructor and I assume its correct if he's giving it out but with these memory errors I don't fully understand what's going on. The only way I'm calling the in a loop to go through the array and outputting the answer like `cout << FiboNR(n[i]);`

Comment: Loop content should be `F[i] = F[i - 1] + F[i - 2];`

Comment: @Jarod42 that's the solution for the problem, and that's the correct answer, why you did not post it as an answer ?

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it however, I made an edit as well but im still receiving the same memory error.

Comment: Are you passing `int n[15]` as an argument to `FiboNR`? There's no way that can work - you'd have to have a cast, and you really shouldn't add casts unless you understand what you're doing. (It would pass the address of `n` as an integer, which would overflow `max` and cause crashes).

Comment: ...you need to show the calling code. It's wrong somehow. -858993460 is 0xcccccccc, which in Windows indicates uninitialized memory.

Comment: Got it to work, one of the files wasn't building when ran. Thank you for all the help, very appreciative.

Comment: Assuming `int` is 32-bits, your function cannot calculate more than about the first 48th elements, therefore it is wasteful to have an array of size 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your trouble is in loop. Replace:

```
    F[n] = F[n - 1] + F[n - 2];
```

with:

```
    F[i] = F[i - 1] + F[i - 2];
```

Because **i** is your iterator and **n** is only the limit.
Just FYI, the braces `( )` in return statement are not needed, you can ignore them.

---

> I am using this array of numbers and passing it to FiboNR

You are not supposed to do that since FiboNR() excepts its argument to be an integer (one, not an array of integers). So you should pass only one number to your function, like: `FiboNR(n[2])`.

Answer (score 0):

You get a negative numbers due to int overflow for int array (n > 46).

Change array type from *int* to *long long*.

Other solutions: change array type to float/double type with less precision of the results or use long arithmetic.

Type | Typical Bit Width | Typical Range

int | 4bytes| -2147483648 to 2147483647

Link: [C++ Data Types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm)

Example of code below.

```
#include <iostream>   

long long FiboNR(int n);    

long long FiboNR(int n) {
  int const max = 100;
  long long F[max];

  if (n > max) {
    n = max;
  }

  F[0] = 0;
  F[1] = 1;

  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
    F[i] = F[i - 1] + F[i - 2];
  }    
  return (F[n]);
}    

int main() {

  for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::cout << "i = " << i << " : " << FiboNR(i) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The largest value in the input array is 70 For signed 32 bit int, the largest value is fib(46) = 1836311903, for unsigned 32 bit int, the largest value is fib(47) = 2971215073. As mentioned, using long long (64 bit int) will be large enough, as fib(92) = 7540113804746346429. For unsigned long long, fib(93) = 12200160415121876738.

Comment: rcgldr, yes, you right. I assume int as in the question. And yes, using "long long (64 bit int)" will be enough for n <= 92 (n = 93 : -6246583658587674878).